# How to change marker image based on search option?

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap

I am developing an application for Finding Near by Places using **Google Maps**.

How can I change the **Marker** Icon based on search option. For example I have searched **Near by Banks** on that time it will show the **Marker** with **Bank image** like that to all search functionality such as **ATM, Hospital**, **Restaurant** and etc.. 
Please help me out.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
// create marker
MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Hello Maps");

// Changing marker icon
marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_marker_icon)));

// adding marker
googleMap.addMarker(marker);
```

here Validate which type of lat-long are you got, use that corresponding icon with use of if condition or switch statement

for more info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker

Comment: Type of lat-long means?

Comment: location's latitude and longitude

Comment: `lat: 17.446495 and long 78.384405, 
lat: 17.4440314 and long 78.38439,
lat: 17.4464897 and long 78.38432209999999,
lat: 17.44560999999999 and long 78.385774,
lat: 17.445615 and long 78.385774` I am getting like this.

Comment: these are bank type